# Ruby Sinatra with consumer thread and job queue

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sinatra

I’m trying to create a very simple restful server. When it receives a request, I want to create a new job on a queue that can be handled by another thread while the current thread returns a response to the client.

I looked at Sinatra, but haven't got too far.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'thread'

queue = Queue.new

set :port, 9090

get '/' do
  queue << 'item'
  length = queue.size
  puts 'QUEUE LENGTH %d', length
  'Message Received'
end

consumer = Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    value = queue.pop(true) rescue nil
    puts "consumed #{value}"
  end
end

consumer.join
```

In the above example, I know the consumer thread would only run a few times (as opposed to the life of the application), but even this isn't working for me.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is your call to [`Queue#pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-pop). You’re passing `true`, which causes it *not* to suspend the thread and raises an exception instead, which you rescue with `nil`. Your consumer thread therefore loops five times before any thing else can happen.

You need to change that line to

```
value = queue.pop
```

so that the thread waits for new data being pushed onto the queue.

You’ll also need to remove the `consumer.join` line from the end, since that will cause deadlock once you’ve changed the call to `pop`.

(Also, it’s not part of your main problem, but it looks like you want [`printf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) rather than `puts` when you print the queue length).

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly and gives me something to build on.  Cheers

Comment: Another small note, $stderr.puts should be used for outputting debug statements in a threaded environment.  The standard output (puts, $stdout.puts, etc) may not actually print in the correct order depending on the implementation which can be very frustrating.  This is because the standard output is usually buffered in a non-thread-friendly manner.  The standard error is very rarely buffered (Even at the kernel level and I think it may even be a standard to not buffer the standard error).  This advice applies to all programming languages and environments.