# Can I redirect before processing input?

Tags: ruby, redirect, optimization, sinatra

What I currently have is this:

```
get "/" do
    submitMeToTheDatabase = veryLongFunction(params[:processme])
    Information.create(complicatedInformation:submitMeToTheDatabase)
    redirect "/otherPage"
end
```

Would it work the same way, but have improved load times for the user if I did this?

```
get "/" do
    redirect "/otherPage"
    submitMeToTheDatabase = veryLongFunction(params[:processme])
    Information.create(complicatedInformation:submitMeToTheDatabase)
end
```

**Addendum**

What would be another way to accomplish the same thing? Something along the lines of:

```
get "/" do
    fork do
        submitMeToTheDatabase = veryLongFunction(params[:processme])
        Information.create(complicatedInformation:submitMeToTheDatabase)
    end
    redirect "/otherPage"
end
```

Comment: What’s `complicatedInformation:submitMeToTheDatabase`? It looks like you’ve made up some example code, but that isn’t even valid syntax.

Comment: @matt Sorry, that's activerecord syntax, I just was making up something that would take a long time to process

Comment: Ah right sorry, it’s the hash syntax. It looks a bit unusual without a space but it’s valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used sinatra, but I don't think the second would work.

The [source](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/52b9a798a71ac3594be44c99f3fa786bbe6c8824/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L250-L261) for the `redirect` method shows that `redirect` calls halt ([source](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/52b9a798a71ac3594be44c99f3fa786bbe6c8824/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L938-L941)) and immediately stops any further processing.

You could put the task onto a job queue and process it on another thread. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024197/ruby-sinatra-with-consumer-thread-and-job-queue) to get an idea of what I mean.

```
queue = Queue.new
get "/" do
    queue << params[:processme]
    redirect "/otherPage"
end

consumer = Thread.new do
    loop do
        data = queue.pop
        submitMe = veryLongFunction(data)
        Information.create(complicatedInformation:submitMeToTheDatabase)
    end
end
```

Code not tested.